# Handling the api error part in jest React testing library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have the following function on form submit. There is no much form validations added for now and i make the post api call and submits the form on clicking save button. I have successfully wrote the test case for the successful form submission and not very sure how to go about the error scenario to cover the `.catch((e) => {}` part in general when the api fails.

```
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<DoctorSettings> = (data) => {
  userUpdateService
    .updateUser(data)
    .then((resp) => {
      UtilsService.popUp("Successfully submitted form", "success");
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      UtilsService.popUp("Error submitting form", "error");
    });
};
```

I wrote the following test case for the successful form submit

```
const updateUser = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve());
jest.mock("../services/userUpdateService.service", () => {
  return function() {
    return {
      updateUser: updateUser,
    };
  };
});
```

```
test("should successfully submit the form when save is clciked", async () => {
          const { findByTestId, getByTestId } = render(props);
        
          const gender = await getByTestId(
            "gender-select"
          ).querySelector('input[type="radio"]');
          // ----------------
          // ----------------
          // ----------------
        
          const saveButton = await findByTestId("save-button");
        
          expect(gender).toBeInTheDocument();
          // ----------------
          // ----------------
          // ----------------
          expect(saveButton).toBeInTheDocument();
        
          await act(async () => {
            fireEvent.click(saveButton);
          });
          expect(updateUser).toBeCalled();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should mock HTTP requests with tools like [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock) After mocking HTTP requests you can trigger an HTTP error with nock. You also should spyOn UtilsService.popup and test it called with correct values.